# how many nuggets can you not buy?

Tags: mathematics

A fast food restaurant sells chicken nuggets in orders of 6, 9, and 20.

What is the largest number of chicken nuggets you cannot order from this restaurant?

Comment: This a commonly known problem, this is not even a variation of it. It's ([ROT13](http://www.rot13.com/) spoiler in case somebody doesn't know the solution): sbheglguerr.

Comment: @LukasRotter Are you sure this is the correct link? It's more like this one: http://goodriddlesnow.com/riddles/view/749

Comment: @RadoslavHristov I linked to a rot-13 deciphering page to decipher the spoiler I posted, I didn't intend to link to a post on another website explaining the solution.

Comment: @LukasRotter Please forgive my natural stupidity! I didn't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>This is being posted as a community answer because rep is not deserved for simply reposting an answer found elsewhere. The [original link](http://goodriddlesnow.com/riddles/view/749) was shared in a [comment by @RadoslavHristov](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41211/41212?noredirect=1#comment121613_41211).</sub>

Answer:

> 43

Because

> After 6 all numbers divisible by 3 can be ordered (because they can all be expressed as a sum of 6's and 9's). After 26, all numbers divisible by three when subtracted by 20 can be obtained. After 46, all numbers divisible by three when subtracted by 40 can be obtained. After 46, all numbers fit into one of these 3 categories, so all numbers can be obtained. 43 is the last number that doesn't fall into one of these categories ($44 = 20 + 6\times4$, $45 = 6\times6 + 9$).

Comment: You could have at least posted a link to the verbatim solution you pasted here and could given a credit to whoever wrote it.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov Your comment, which contains the link, was mentioned in the first sentence. The original author is probably unknown, it's just a generic riddle, [you can find it all over the place](https://www.google.com/search?q=6+9+20+puzzle), you'd have to do significant research to find the author.

Comment: @JasonC If you are referring to the Lukas's comment, I agree, I didn't see it. As for this answer - the top section was added after my comment and I don't know even how to create that kind of text. I still stay on my position that copying and pasting verbatim answers from the internet is incorrect (as is doing the same with the questions themselves).

Comment: @RadoslavHristov That's why it was posted as CW, which deserves appreciation, not criticism.

Comment: @JasonC I will re-iterate that it was changed to community answer AFTER my comment, what's not clear on this part?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov TIt's not a big deal, but the answer was originally posted as a wiki. For what it's worth, I've copied the link from your comment and added it as well as linking back to your original comment.

Comment: @EngineerToast Hey man, no hard feelings, I wrote what I wrote but due to the fact that posts can be edited, sometimes, after a while it looks different. In any case, the question itself should have been ditched in the first place.